# Discontinued button on products sold out

Tags: shopify, liquid

so I am, trying to add a discontinued button on products that are out of stock and have the tag "Discontinued". I have managed to add this, however, I have a few issues:

The button still shows on in-stock items
A blank button appears on products without the tag "Discontinued" I don't want it showing on any products without the mentioned tag?
Can anyone help/guide me, please? I have attached images and the code I use.

```
 {%- assign enable_dynamic_buttons = false -%}
  {% if settings.enable_payment_button and template != 'product.preorder' %}
    {%- assign enable_dynamic_buttons = true -%}
  {% endif %}
 
  {% if enable_dynamic_buttons %}
    <div class="payment-buttons">
  {% endif %}
 
    <button
      {% if product.empty? %}type="button"{% else %}type="submit"{% endif %}
      name="add"
      id="AddToCart-{{ section_id }}"
      class="btn btn--full add-to-cart{% if enable_dynamic_buttons %} btn--secondary{% endif %}"
      {% unless current_variant.available %} disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}>
      <span id="AddToCartText-{{ section_id }}">
        {% if current_variant.available %}
          {% if template == 'product.preorder' %}
            {{ 'products.product.preorder' | t }}
          {% else %}
            {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
        {% endif %}
      </span>
    </button>
 
    {% if enable_dynamic_buttons %}
      {{ form | payment_button }}
    {% endif %}
 
  {% if enable_dynamic_buttons %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
 
  <div class="btn btn--full "> 
      {% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% if tag contains 'Discontinued' %}
    <span>SORRY THIS ITEM IS DISCONTINUED</span>
  {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Comment: What is `product.empty?` this expected to do?

Comment: if product empty disable submit button else show submit. Regarding the discontinued button here are ways i have tried > {% comment %}
  <div class="btn btn--full"> 
      {% for tag in product.tags %} 
  {% if tag contains 'Discontinued' %}
    <span>SORRY THIS ITEM IS DISCONTINUED</span>
  {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
 {% endcomment %}

Comment: @shaneleevans Isn't that `product.available` ?

Comment: Actually yes I think you are right. Go on this link https://bqkgkatub0u3elwr-40925135001.shopifypreview.com and in the search bar type discontinued then scroll down and click on WOMEN'S LIBERTY RUBBER ANKLE BOOTS. Here you will see my discontinued section which works how I want it apart from it also showing on in-stock products which i do not want!!

Answer (score 0):

You `if...else` conditions around the discontinued tags are wrong. Try this

```
{%- assign enable_dynamic_buttons = false -%}
{% if settings.enable_payment_button and template != 'product.preorder' %}
{%- assign enable_dynamic_buttons = true -%}
{% endif %}

{% if enable_dynamic_buttons %}
<div class="payment-buttons">
{% endif %}

    <button
        {% if product.available %}type="submit"{% endif %}
        name="add"
        id="AddToCart-{{ section_id }}"
        class="btn btn--full add-to-cart{% if enable_dynamic_buttons %} btn--secondary{% endif %}"
        {% unless current_variant.available %} disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}
    >
        {% if current_variant.available %}
        <span id="AddToCartText-{{ section_id }}">
            {% if template == 'product.preorder' %}
            {{ 'products.product.preorder' | t }}
            {% else %}
            {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
            {% endif %}
        </span>
            {% if enable_dynamic_buttons %}
            {{ form | payment_button }}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
            {% if product.tags contains 'Discontinued' %}
            <div class="btn btn--full "> 
                <span>SORRY THIS ITEM IS DISCONTINUED</span>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    </button>

{% if enable_dynamic_buttons %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried yours and it completely removes everything else I need? see here https://bqkgkatub0u3elwr-40925135001.shopifypreview.com I still need everything else I had before but just for the button only to show on products tagged with 'Discontinued' and are sold out

Comment: Do you want to show "Add to cart" & "Buy now" buttons on the products with the discontinued tag?

Comment: if they are not sold out yet then yes but without discontinued button. if they are sold out then show sold out button and discontinued

Comment: Your `if...else` conditions are completely wrong for what you require. Updated the answer.

Comment: i get this error > This file contains the following errors:
Line 40 — Liquid syntax error: 'if' tag was never closed

Comment: Umm not quite https://bqkgkatub0u3elwr-40925135001.shopifypreview.com

Comment: it shows once then goes plus it has messed up my button styles

Comment: I corrected the order/styling of the buttons. Check it now. Beyond that is out of scope for this question. I provide the correct implementation of your required logic. You should be able to take it from there. If not, please hire someone to make the page as per your requirement :)